# Как создавать функции прямо в eval (или exec)

Tags: python

Представим такую ситуацию что у нас есть программа по типу такой:

```
while True:
    eval(input("> "))
```

И человек вводит `def foo():`
Как мне при этом выполнить это без `SyntaxError`?

И при этом чтобы пользователь смог потом выполнить:

```
foo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сварганить что-нибудь по типу самого питоновсого интерпретатора, который в интерактивном режиме в таком случае ждёт пустой строки, и только потом исполняет код.

```
while True:
    code = [input(">>> ")]
    if code[-1].rstrip().endswith(":"):
        while code[-1]:
            code.append(input("... "))
    exec("\n".join(code))
```

Или вперемешку с `eval`, если именно он вам так важен.

```
while True:
    code = [input(">>> ")]
    if code[-1].rstrip().endswith(":"):
        while code[-1]:
            code.append(input("... "))
        exec("\n".join(code))
    else:
        eval(code[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(input(f”{foo()} >20 ”))
```

Можно попробовать лямбду функцию:

```
x = eval(input(" lambda x : x > 10"))
```

Потом где-то в коде использовать так: `x(19)`

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы человек мог не пользоваться функциями, а создавать их